# SharePoint lists, unique to user

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list which has multiple users, is there a way that when each user opens the list they can only see the row relevant to them?

Comment: You can modify default view maybe (so that it filters only the item which are relevant). Or just create some sort of second "my relevant items" view.

Comment: If I created a second view how would I get that to only show the users items who has logged in, would that nit just create a second view for everyone?

Comment: The views are for everyone. So the users can use them to filter items which are relevant to them. You can put a filtering condition to filter by  current user for example, like "task assigned to me", "items created by me" etc. You can use [me] to refer to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the view, and add a filter:

Column: Created by

is equal to

[Me]

Then each person who looks at that view will see only the items they created. [Me] compares the column to the currently logged in username.